# Writing a proper implementation of compareTo

Tags: java, sorting, comparable, custom-compare

```java
private static class CharacterIndex implements Comparable<CharacterIndex> {
    private final char c;
    private final int index;

    public CharacterIndex(char c, int index) {
        this.c = c;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

Now I want to override the `compareTo` method for this class such that if I have the following `List` of `CharacterIndex`'s objects `[('y', 1), ('x', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 3)]` then after sorting, the objects should be like `[('b', 3), ('a', 3), ('x', 2), ('y', 1)]`.

### Sorting Strategy:

**Objects for which the index is different can be shuffled (and should be in sorted order based only on the character's value). Objects that have same index should maintain their relative order after sorting.**

#### One more example:

For `[('y', 1), ('w', 2), ('x', 3)]` the sorted list should be `[(w, 2), (x, 3), (y, 1)]` and not `[(x, 3), (w, 2), (y, 1)]`.

### My attempt:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(CharacterIndex ci) {
    if (this.index == ci.index)
        return -1; // don't swap if the index is same
    return Character.compare(this.c, ci.c);
}
```

But this approach gives me an exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:866)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:483)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:422)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:222)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1312)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1506)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:141)
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469308/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract). But I couldn't clearly understand why am I getting this exception.

Is there a better way to sort the `List<CharacterIndex>` with the above given strategy?

Comment: `return -1; // don't swap if the index is same` That's not what -1 means here. Returning -1 means that `this` sorts before `ci`. If what you want is for them to _not_ swap, then that means they sort the same, and that means you want to return 0.

Comment: @yshavit That's not exactly correct. If you return `0` it means the two elements are "equal" and may be shuffled among themselves, depending on the sorting algorithm.

Comment: @RealSkeptic True. I was trying to keep things relatively simple and shortcut that a bit, since the JDK sorting algorithms are all (afaik) stable. But that's a good call-out for the next level of detail.

Comment: Your sorting strategy does not seem to define a proper total order. For example, consider `(b,1),(c,3),(a,3)`. How do you order them? The `(b,1)` has to come before the `(c,3)`, but after the `(a,3)`, but since you can't reorder the `(c,3)` and the `(a,3)`, you cannot order this combination at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting @RealSkeptic's comments into answer:

#### The [java-docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of `Comparable` says that:

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it.

#### Total-ordering should follow the following properties:

- Reflexivity
- Antisymmetry
- Transitivity
- Comparability

To see more on what totally ordered sets are see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotallyOrderedSet.html) link.

#### My sorting strategy is not transitive.

Suppose my initial list is `[(d,2), (y,1), (b,1)]`

- `(y,1) < (b,1)` as for same index, I don't want to shuffle the order.
- `(b,1) < (d,2)` as for different index, I can shuffle order and then I need to compare the character only.

By transitivity, `(y,1) < (d, 2)`. Which is not true.

So this is not a totally ordered comparison. And hence it breaks the rule provided by `Comparable` interface.

So we can't have a correct implementation of `compareTo` (which abide by the contract of `Comparable` interface) for this sorting strategy.

#### What you learned?

Your sorting strategy should always define total ordering on the objects of class that implements `Comparable`

Comment: Another important thing you should have learned is that returning `-1` doesn't mean "do not switch". In classical quicksort, for example, you pick a "pivot", and put everything that's lower to its left, and everything that's higher to its right. This would mean that elements that returned `-1` *would* be moved before that element.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `o1.compareTo(o2) == -1 && o2.compareTo(o1) == -1` if `o1.index == o2.index`. The contract for `compareTo` method is that those two must be of different signs: `o1.compareTo(o2)` and `o2.compareTo(o1)`.

In other words this means both that `o1` is less than `o2` and `o2` is less than `o1`, which is impossible.

Possible solution:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(CharacterIndex ci) {
    return Character.compare(this.c, ci.c);
}
```

Here we are comparing by character it carries. As @RealSkeptic noticed, there is no way to take index into account as the relation is no longer transitive.

Comment: @Andronicus I don't understand your possible solution. Can you please elaborate and explain what can be the possible solution.

Comment: @LavishKothari added description, hope it helps!

Comment: @Andronicus I don't understand what is `this.c.index`? I've edited the question and added this example: for `[('y', 1), ('w', 2), ('x', 3)]` the sorted list should be `[(w, 2), (x, 3), (y, 1)]` instead of `[(x, 3), (w, 2), (y, 1)]`

Comment: @Andronicus In your edited answer: How does your possible solution maintain the original order between two elements with the same index?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, LavishKothari yes, that was wrong, I'm sorry. Now that I know the fields I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I didn't notice that. So I can't see any solution to take index into account.

Comment: Indeed, because the OP's sorting strategy does not define a proper total order.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thank you much for clarification, I've edited the answer